# How to get array values within an array using PHP?

Tags: php

Hello guys I just want to ask how can i get the array values within an array? I also used the unserialize function and it returns to array. That's why I got a lists of array.

Here's my sample output for the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 332
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [points] => 100
                    [cost] => 100
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1552
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [points] => 100
                    [cost] => 100
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1885
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [points] => 294
                    [cost] => 294
                )

        )
     .
     .
```

Now I loop it again to assign in a variable:

```
 for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($var_data); $x++){

            echo "ID: ".$var_data[$x]['id']."<br />";

            foreach($var_data as $key => $value){
                // it is the part that i don't know how to get the data array values and assign in a varaile.
            }

 }
```

Here's what i want to do:

```
ID: 1
COST: 100.00
TOTAL: 100.00

ID: 2
COST: 65.00
TOTAL: 65.00

ID: 3
COST: 40.00
TOTAL: 40.00
.
.
```

How can I do that? Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `foreach`.

```
foreach($var_data as $data)
{
    echo "ID: ".$data['id']."<br />";
    echo "COST: ".$data['data']['cost']."<br />";
    echo "TOTAL: ".$data['data']['points']."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach

```
$output= '';
foreach($var_data as $data) {
  $output = '<div>';
  $output= '<p>ID: '.$data['id'].'</p>';
  $output= '<p>COST: '.$data['data']['cost'].'</p>';
  $output= '<p>TOTAL: '.$data['data']['points'].'</p>';
}

echo $output;
```